# Как быстро записывать данные в QOpenGlBuffer

Tags: qt, opengl

```
void initialize(...)
{
...
frame_pbo = new QOpenGLBuffer(QOpenGLBuffer::PixelUnpackBuffer);
frame_pbo->create();
frame_pbo->bind();
frame_pbo->setUsagePattern(QOpenGLBuffer::StaticDraw);
frame_pbo->release();
...
}
```

вот тут я получаю кадр, записываю в pbo

```
const quint8* data = frame->getData(stream_num);

frame_width = frame->getWidth(stream_num);
frame_height = frame->getHeight(stream_num);
frame_pbo->bind();
if (const QSize fsize{ frame_width, frame_height }; _frame_size != fsize)
{
    _frame_size = fsize;
    frame_pbo->allocate(_frame_size.width() * _frame_size.height() * 3);
}

current_ticks = clock();
frame_pbo->write(0, data, frame_width * frame_height * 3);
delta_ticks1 = clock() - current_ticks;
....
```

проблема заключается в том, что write работает слишком медленно, чтобы отображать данные в среднем значение ~40мс на кадр с разрешением 7680×4320 ( по три пикселя на цвет)
как можно это ускорить?

**довелось ускорить, заменив write**

```
current_ticks = clock();
auto ptr = frame_pbo->mapRange(0, _frame_size.width() * _frame_size.height() * 3, QOpenGLBuffer::RangeInvalidateBuffer | QOpenGLBuffer::RangeWrite);
memcpy(ptr, data, _frame_size.width() * _frame_size.height() * 3);
frame_pbo->unmap();
std::cout << "map \t" << clock() - current_ticks << std::endl;
```

просто это дало прирост:
На 1098 кадров write занимал 47,065 ms, переделав на maprange -> тот же видеофайл с теми же кажрами, уже 26,597 ms

gl для отображения:

```
frame_pbo->unmap();
QOpenGLFunctions* f = QOpenGLContext::currentContext()->functions();
f->glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
f->glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
f->glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture_id);
f->glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ROW_LENGTH, frame_width);
f->glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_SKIP_PIXELS, 0);
f->glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB8, frame_width, frame_height, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, nullptr);
f->glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ROW_LENGTH, 0);
f->glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_SKIP_PIXELS, 0);

glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
frame_pbo->release();
```

Comment: https://forum.qt.io/topic/60651/updating-data-in-a-qopenglbuffer/10

Comment: @KoVadim, поставил вместо write mapRange и ощутил явный прирост производительности стало в разы лучше, но все еще есть куда стремится, спасибо!

Comment: поделитесь измерениями?

Comment: @KoVadim, для начала, я хочу до последней милисекунды выжать из программы. На 1098 кадров write занимал 47,065 ms, переделав на maprange -> тот же видеофайл с теми же кажрами, уже 26,597 ms

Comment: думаю, ещё нужно со StaticDraw поиграться. Если Вы постоянно обновляете картинку, то явно там не StaticDraw должен быть. Второе - возможно, нужно использовать упакованные текстуры (если я правильно понял, что это текстуры)

Comment: @KoVadim, да, это я как текстурку накладываю

Comment: посмотрите на это https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/S3_Texture_Compression - если там такие размеры, то может быть упаковка текстуры будет быстрее, чем пересылка неупакованной. Но это нужно мерять

Comment: @KoVadim, тоесть вместо того. чтобы мне перекидывать в pbo чистый ргб, до этого его попробовать упаковать?

Comment: да да, я не знаю, где берутся эти текстуры, но может будет легко их в упакованный вид переводить